# El .difference en Django debería retornar una queryset pero devuelve vacío?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Django Rest Framework. Entre mis modelos tengo uno llamado Perfiles que le pertenece a un usuario. Cuando se inserta un usuario se le agregan perfiles, y cuando se modifica el usuario se le modifican los perfiles también.

Cuando se modifica el usuario la información la recibo por un request, en el mismo viene el listado de perfiles para actualizar. Para comparar los perfiles y actualizar, utilizo el [difference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#difference) pero tengo un problema cuando no recibo perfiles al actualizar.

Por ejemplo, esto no da problemas:

```
perfiles_viejos : <QuerySet [<UserProfile: UserProfile object>, <UserProfile: UserProfile object>]>

perfiles_nuevos : <QuerySet [<UserProfile: UserProfile object>, <UserProfile: UserProfile object>]>
```

Donde `perfiles_nuevos` y `perfiles_viejos` son querysets con datos de mis perfiles. Con el difference comparo ambos querysets y con la diferencia hago la actualización. Hasta ahi todo bien. Sin embargo:

```
perfiles_viejos : <QuerySet [<UserProfile: UserProfile object>, <UserProfile: UserProfile object>]>

perfiles_nuevos : <QuerySet []>
```

Aquí es cuando tengo un error. Si comparo `perfiles_viejos` contra `perfiles_nuevos` empleando difference, yo debería obtener todos los elementos de `perfiles_viejos`, pero obtengo vacío!

Probe lo siguiente en la consola:

```
c1 = {1,2,3}
c2 = {3,4,5}
c3 = {}
c1.difference(c2)
>>>{1,2}
c1.difference(c3)
>>>{1,2,3}
```

Aquí el difference retorna los elementos que debería. Por que en mi código no pasa esto?

Gracias de antemano y perdón por la ortografía, mi teclado tiene problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te manda error por que estas comparando dos cosas diferentes, aunque también puedes condicionar para evitar esto. pero intenta lo siguiente.

si conviertes los datos a `set` te dará el resultado correcto.

```
set(perfiles_viejos).difference(set(perfiles_nuevos))
```

ya que los dos tipos de datos son iguales.

Saludos

Comment: TIO MIL GRACIAS!!! Esto ha funcionado de maravillas, les puse el set y ya no da problemas. Llevaba una semana sin poder resolver mi problema.